# Online Marketplace Payment System

Tags: reactjs, django, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I'm building a website like ebay where sellers post listings and users can buy them. I want it so that buyers are able to pay sellers directly, and I take a percentage of the sale. Is Stripe Connect the correct product to use? I want it so that buyers do not need a stripe account to pay, they only need to enter their credit card info and hit pay. If not, what are some alternative payment systems I can use?

Comment: This question does not meet the [so] guidelines. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Stripe Connect, and this is the [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide) that you should follow.

The customers don't need to have Stripe accounts to make payments, but you need to create connected accounts for your sellers. Make sure you onboard them
properly so that they can start collecting payments from customers.